# Combine several SVG <path>

Tags: svg, sprite

I need to know how to combine multiple  from a SVG file.
Right now I have three icons and somehow I can not find any logic behind that.

I read that I need to remove the last part and combine it with the following.

Example:

*From*

```
<path d="m150.355469 322.332031c-30.046875 0-54.402344 24.355469-54.402344 54.402344 0 30.042969 24.355469 54.398437 54.402344 54.398437 30.042969 0 54.398437-24.355468 54.398437-54.398437-.03125-30.03125-24.367187-54.371094-54.398437-54.402344zm0 88.800781c-19 0-34.402344-15.402343-34.402344-34.398437 0-19 15.402344-34.402344 34.402344-34.402344 18.996093 0 34.398437 15.402344 34.398437 34.402344 0 18.996094-15.402344 34.398437-34.398437 34.398437zm0 0"/><path d="m446.855469 94.035156h-353.101563l-7.199218-40.300781c-4.4375-24.808594-23.882813-44.214844-48.699219-48.601563l-26.101563-4.597656c-5.441406-.96875-10.632812 2.660156-11.601562 8.097656-.964844 5.441407 2.660156 10.632813 8.101562 11.601563l26.199219 4.597656c16.53125 2.929688 29.472656 15.871094 32.402344 32.402344l35.398437 199.699219c4.179688 23.894531 24.941406 41.324218 49.199219 41.300781h210c22.0625.066406 41.546875-14.375 47.902344-35.5l47-155.800781c.871093-3.039063.320312-6.3125-1.5-8.898438-1.902344-2.503906-4.859375-3.980468-8-4zm-56.601563 162.796875c-3.773437 12.6875-15.464844 21.367188-28.699218 21.300781h-210c-14.566407.039063-27.035157-10.441406-29.5-24.800781l-24.699219-139.398437h336.097656zm0 0"/>
```

TO

```
<path d="m150.355469 322.332031c-30.046875 0-54.402344 24.355469-54.402344 54.402344 0 30.042969 24.355469 54.398437 54.402344 54.398437 30.042969 0 54.398437-24.355468 54.398437-54.398437-.03125-30.03125-24.367187-54.371094-54.398437-54.402344zm0 88.800781c-19 0-34.402344-15.402343-34.402344-34.398437 0-19 15.402344-34.402344 34.402344-34.402344 18.996093 0 34.398437 15.402344 34.398437 34.402344 0 18.996094-15.402344 34.398437-34.398437 34.398437 m446.855469 94.035156h-353.101563l-7.199218-40.300781c-4.4375-24.808594-23.882813-44.214844-48.699219-48.601563l-26.101563-4.597656c-5.441406-.96875-10.632812 2.660156-11.601562 8.097656-.964844 5.441407 2.660156 10.632813 8.101562 11.601563l26.199219 4.597656c16.53125 2.929688 29.472656 15.871094 32.402344 32.402344l35.398437 199.699219c4.179688 23.894531 24.941406 41.324218 49.199219 41.300781h210c22.0625.066406 41.546875-14.375 47.902344-35.5l47-155.800781c.871093-3.039063.320312-6.3125-1.5-8.898438-1.902344-2.503906-4.859375-3.980468-8-4zm-56.601563 162.796875c-3.773437 12.6875-15.464844 21.367188-28.699218 21.300781h-210c-14.566407.039063-27.035157-10.441406-29.5-24.800781l-24.699219-139.398437h336.097656zm0 0"/>
```

But the output is empty.
And if I only take one path of both I will see only this path.

Is there any easy explanation how to do that?

Comment: Are you expecting people to visually compare those two strings of numbers to tell what is different? Are they different?

Comment: It's empty probably because you didn't set a viewBox attribute. I suppose the paths are falling outside the svg canvas. Please edit the question by adding the svg label as you have it.

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize your paths if you put them in a suitable `<svg>` element. It needs to have a "sensible" viewBox attribute in it. For your example the following works: `<svg viewBox="0 0 620 840">`. I also added two rectangles (`<rect>`) to show the extent of your overlaying symbols.

Note: To actually combine two paths into one is a slightly more complex task. This can be done with a suitable graphical SVG-editor, like Inkscape (or many others ...).

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 620 840">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="480" height="440" style="stroke:black;fill:none"/>
    <path d="m150.355469 322.332031c-30.046875 0-54.402344 24.355469-54.402344 54.402344 0 30.042969 24.355469 54.398437 54.402344 54.398437 30.042969 0 54.398437-24.355468 54.398437-54.398437-.03125-30.03125-24.367187-54.371094-54.398437-54.402344zm0 88.800781c-19 0-34.402344-15.402343-34.402344-34.398437 0-19 15.402344-34.402344 34.402344-34.402344 18.996093 0 34.398437 15.402344 34.398437 34.402344 0 18.996094-15.402344 34.398437-34.398437 34.398437zm0 0"/><path d="m446.855469 94.035156h-353.101563l-7.199218-40.300781c-4.4375-24.808594-23.882813-44.214844-48.699219-48.601563l-26.101563-4.597656c-5.441406-.96875-10.632812 2.660156-11.601562 8.097656-.964844 5.441407 2.660156 10.632813 8.101562 11.601563l26.199219 4.597656c16.53125 2.929688 29.472656 15.871094 32.402344 32.402344l35.398437 199.699219c4.179688 23.894531 24.941406 41.324218 49.199219 41.300781h210c22.0625.066406 41.546875-14.375 47.902344-35.5l47-155.800781c.871093-3.039063.320312-6.3125-1.5-8.898438-1.902344-2.503906-4.859375-3.980468-8-4zm-56.601563 162.796875c-3.773437 12.6875-15.464844 21.367188-28.699218 21.300781h-210c-14.566407.039063-27.035157-10.441406-29.5-24.800781l-24.699219-139.398437h336.097656zm0 0"/>
    <rect x="80" y="300" width="540" height="440" style="stroke:black;fill:none"/>
  <g style="fill:none;stroke:red">
    <path d="m150.355469 322.332031c-30.046875 0-54.402344 24.355469-54.402344 54.402344 0 30.042969 24.355469 54.398437 54.402344 54.398437 30.042969 0 54.398437-24.355468 54.398437-54.398437-.03125-30.03125-24.367187-54.371094-54.398437-54.402344zm0 88.800781c-19 0-34.402344-15.402343-34.402344-34.398437 0-19 15.402344-34.402344 34.402344-34.402344 18.996093 0 34.398437 15.402344 34.398437 34.402344 0 18.996094-15.402344 34.398437-34.398437 34.398437 m446.855469 94.035156h-353.101563l-7.199218-40.300781c-4.4375-24.808594-23.882813-44.214844-48.699219-48.601563l-26.101563-4.597656c-5.441406-.96875-10.632812 2.660156-11.601562 8.097656-.964844 5.441407 2.660156 10.632813 8.101562 11.601563l26.199219 4.597656c16.53125 2.929688 29.472656 15.871094 32.402344 32.402344l35.398437 199.699219c4.179688 23.894531 24.941406 41.324218 49.199219 41.300781h210c22.0625.066406 41.546875-14.375 47.902344-35.5l47-155.800781c.871093-3.039063.320312-6.3125-1.5-8.898438-1.902344-2.503906-4.859375-3.980468-8-4zm-56.601563 162.796875c-3.773437 12.6875-15.464844 21.367188-28.699218 21.300781h-210c-14.566407.039063-27.035157-10.441406-29.5-24.800781l-24.699219-139.398437h336.097656zm0 0"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I combined the two paths of your second part using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org), put it through the online SVG optimizer [SVGOMG!](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) (thanks for the hint, [Danny '365CSI' Engelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520800/danny-365csi-engelman)) and ended up with this:

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
width="400" viewBox="-1 0 515 390">
<path d="M54.4 2a54.4 54.4 0 106.2 108.4
c9.1 2.2 18.9 3.5 28.3 5.2
a40 40 0 0132.4 32.4l35.4 199.7a49.9 49.9 0 0049.2 41.3
h210c22 0 41.5-14.4 47.9-35.5l47-155.8
c.8-3 .3-6.3-1.5-8.9-2-2.5-4.9-4-8-4H148.2l-7.2-40.3
c-7-24.4-13.6-38.3-49.2-48.7A54.2 54.2 0 0054.4 2zm0 20
a34.4 34.4 0 110 68.8 34.4 34.4 0 010-68.8z
m97.4 182.7h336l-43.1 142.9a29.8 29.8 0 01-28.7 21.3H206
c-14.6 0-27-10.4-29.5-24.8z" 
stroke="red" fill="gray"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: After that, process your SVG file with [SVGMO](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) the 5 digit precision in above SVG is like stuffing 100.000 pixels into 1

Comment: Thanks, that's a good one! SVGMO is what I've been looking for for quite a while. Very helpful.

Comment: Recently found this great online editor: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ Helps in getting rid of translates and scaling viewBox

Answer (score 1):

If you then take your path:

```
M54.4 2a54.4 54.4 0 106.2 108.4c9.1 2.2 18.9 3.5 28.3 5.2a40 40 0 0132.4 32.4l35.4 99.7a49.9 49.9 0 0049.2 41.3h210c22 0 41.5-14.4 47.9-35.5l47-155.8c.8-3 .3-6.3-1.5-8.9-2-2.5-4.9-4-8-4H148.2l-7.2-40.3c-7-24.4-13.6-38.3-49.2-48.7A54.2 54.2 0 0054.4 2zm0 20a34.4 34.4 0 110 68.8 34.4 34.4 0 010-68.8zm97.4 182.7h336l-43.1 142.9a29.8 29.8 0 01-28.7 1.3H206c-14.6 0-27-10.4-29.5-24.8z
```

and multiply it by 10 using: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

You get rid of all decimal notation and make the file even smaller:

```
M 544 20 a 544 544 90 1 0 62 1084 c 91 22 189 35 283 52 a 400 400 90 0 1 324 324 l 354 1997 a 499 499 90 0 0 492 413 h 2100 c 220 0 415 -144 479 -355 l 470 -1558 c 8 -30 3 -63 -15 -89 c -20 -25 -49 -40 -80 -40 H 1482 l -72 -403 c -70 -244 -136 -383 -492 -487 A 542 542 90 0 0 544 20 z m 0 200 a 344 344 90 1 1 0 688 a 344 344 90 0 1 0 -688 z m 974 1827 h 3360 l -431 1429 a 298 298 90 0 1 -287 213 H 2060 c -146 0 -270 -104 -295 -248 z
```

The viewBox ofcourse needs to be multiplied as well. As the (default) stroke-width="1"

```html
<svg width="400" viewBox="0 0 5150 3900">
<path d="M544 20a544 544 90 1 0 62 1084c91 22 189 35 283 52a400 400 90 0 1 324 324l354 1997
         a499 499 90 0 0 492 413h2100c220 0 415-144 479-355l470-1558c8-30 3-63-15-89
         c-20-25-49-40-80-40h-3531l-72-403c-70-244-136-383-492-487a542 542 90 0 0-374-938z
         m0 200a344 344 90 1 1 0 688a344 344 90 0 1 0-688z
         m974 1827h3360l-431 1429a298 298 90 0 1-287 213h-2100c-146 0-270-104-295-248z" 
stroke="red" stroke-width="10" fill="gray"/>
</svg>
```

You can save 30 bytes more in the path if you now divide everything by 6

```
M90 3a90 90 90 1 0 10 180c15 4 31 6 47 9a66 66 90 0 1 54 54l59 332a83 83 90 0 0 82 69h349c37 0 69-24 80-59l78-259c1-5 0-10-2-15c-3-4-8-7-13-7h-588l-12-67c-12-41-23-64-82-81a90 90 90 0 0-62-156zm0 33a57 57 90 1 1 0 114a57 57 90 0 1 0-114zm162 303h558l-72 237a49 49 90 0 1-48 35h-348c-24 0-45-17-49-41z
```